# How to prevent user deletion from WordPress dashboard

Tags: wordpress

The question is simple. I need to make it impossible to delete a user account in the WordPress backend for every other user. Is there any function I can add to `functions.php` to achieve this?

Comment: I'd look for a permissions plugin to get that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `delete_user` action hook fires immediately before a user is deleted from the database. Use priority `0` and cross your fingers you're the only one hooking on that priority :)

```
add_action( 'delete_user', 'so27135610_delete_user', 0, 2 );
function so27135610_delete_user( $id, $reassign )
{
    die( "You're not allowed to delete users on this site." );
}
```